# Scrutinizer Laravel 5.2 could not be analyzed

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, scrutinizer

Since I upgraded Laravel to 5.2, Scrutinizer throws an error saying that it couldn't be analyzed:

[image: Error Meesage]

My `composer.json` is:

```
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
```

I already tried to exclude the vendor folder, but this didn't help:

```
filter:
    paths:
        - 'app/*'
    excluded_paths:
        - 'app/views/*'
        - 'app/config/*'
        - 'app/database/*'
        - 'vendor/*'
```

Why does this happen and how can I tell Scrutinizer to ignore this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I reported this to their support. They got back to me saying it had been fixed, and I was able to complete the inspection.

So, this should be working for you now. If it isn't, you need to email their support team (`support@scrutinizer-ci.com`).